# *ngFor Not display all fusion chart graphs

Tags: angular

I have fusion charts in *ngFor, All data coming fine but sometimes not showing all graphs, using ngx-pagination also. Also using *ngIf so that should render only when data loaded. Its not happening each times. Sometimes its showing.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of apiValues | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }; trackBy:identify ">
        <td> {{item.AreaName}} </td>
        <td>
            <div [@popOverState]="stateName">
                <fusioncharts width="100%" height="100" type="hlineargauge" dataformat="json" [dataSource]="item.graph1">

                </fusioncharts>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div [@popOverState]="stateName">
                <fusioncharts width="100%" height="90" type="hlineargauge" dataformat="json" [dataSource]="item.graph2">
                </fusioncharts>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: In order to narrow down your issue: did you try to remove the pagination?

Comment: ya i removed then also same issue, sometimes loading all graphs, sometimes not

Comment: Well, it is kind of complicated to give solid advice for a non-reproducible issue.